# How to break an object with dynamic hair?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, hair

For some weeks I try to break a rigid body with dynamic hair (grass). My starting point was break the mesh and then make it hairy and dynamic. But every fraction have to get set to dynamic individually. The result was crazy dancing hair, which turns.

How to give the entire mesh dynamic hair ( if possible on just one side ) and break it?

Extended version. I have a cube with dynamic grass on the top. Now I want to make an Object break through my grassy floor. But when I use the fraction tool to subdivide and split my floor, the grass disappear. It is no problem to enable the grass particle system on the top fractions, but it's hard to set grass on the top surface of the top fractions. And it is impossible to port the dynamic grass settings, cause they are not transfered to the other fractions via the particle system.

Is there a better way to reach what I want?

Comment: select what part of mesh you need the hair particles. Then you can make the vertex group and under the particles group add the vertex group

Comment: Thank you. So one point is done. But how to combine hair with fractions?

Comment: i did not get what you mean combine hair with fractions? Do you mean you want to join the mesh?

Comment: When I use the fraction tool I get a lot of objects, and I don't want to set up the dynamic hair for every single object (about 250).

Comment: maybe this video help for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvaByzVHJss

Comment: Question edited. I can upload my current project, so you see the problem yourself.